# GitStack - "Forbidden" after installation

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, git, services

Was looking for an easy Git-stack to install on my Windows server. Found GitStack which would be perfect for my own projects.

The only problem is that it throws me a "FORBIDDEN" error after I install it.  Tried uninstalling, running installer as Admin, no use.

Of course I used Google but I couldn't find anything.

**OS:** Windows 7 x86 SP1

Answer (score 0):

Are you running IIS on the server by any chance?

GitStack also tries to run a web server (Apache) on port 80 by default.

If you stop IIS and then run GitStack, you can change the port that it runs on.